# Do all php scripts, even running in different iframes, are rolled one after the other, or can they happen at the same time?

Tags: php, iframe, scripting, simultaneous

I'm programing an Hearthstone-like card game using php (which I know, ain't suited for this at all, but I just like challenging tasks, (and okay, that's the only language i'm familiar with)).

No flash, so the board.php (ROOT OF ALL EVIL) consists of 200+ visible iframes (that's in order for graphic refreshes not to encompass all the screen for a mere health refresh on a card) as well as 4 invisible iframes which all have their specific task : A-chat_refresher (checking for incoming chat messages and friend requests), B-game_refresher (is refreshed every X seconds (player-set value)) : Only executes whatever is sent to a DB table containing info about graphical refreshes needed - which frame(s) to refresh, with a bunch of GET parameters appended to the frame's url), C- move_evaluator (yields results for drag and drops made by the user) and D- instant_executer (responsible for rolling global instants triggered by events > instants > sub-instants ONE AT A TIME).

Basically I gotta keep multiple 'instants' or actions if you prefer from triggering while another set of global event/instant - instants - sub-instants is rolling. This includes NEVER calling more than one function that has an event into it into the same rolling snippet, EXCEPT if I roll a while $_SESSION["phase"] == "EndOfTurnEffects" (sleep(1); (that happens in script A); which as per my wishes should keep on sleeping until $_SESSION["phase"] == "StandBy" (other player's turn), and I wish script B to mofity $_SESSION["phase"]. Basically if script B does not run before script A is done executing, I'm caught in an endless loop of the while statement...

I may actually test it on my own, but I thought others' entry on the matter may help other people too...

Comment: This does not look like a PHP problem or something PHP can solve. You probably need a Javascript/Ajax combination to update separate Iframes.

Comment: Move evaluator is mostly php driving javascript by filling an $onLoad passed to body tag at end (it,s invisble). It is invoked anytime the user drags something draggable and drops it on droppable target. Php also simply drops lines in a db table having for columns "frame" (to refresh) "script_to_invoke", "side" (local or other client (yes this is doubled-client-server here)) which are executed by the refresher, the only frame that actually refreshes each 0.3 to 2s according to user,s settings). To be honest this model was so simple to come up with, compared to dealing with chain reactions...

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside opinions on what you want to do and how you want to do it:

You can have as many concurrent requests open as your configuration and/or resources allow, but only one PHP process can have a given session file open at a time. Unless you explicitly close the session with something like [`session_write_close()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) [or don't open one in the first place] all other connections attempting to open that session will block until the session is closed, and each of those blocking sessions will use up a worker process slot in Apache/Nginx/etc.

That said, with 200+ auto-refreshing iframes per user, and what I imagine is 2+ users per game, you're going to have so many open requests blocking on each other that you're rapidly going to overpower your server and your user experience will be... bad.

You should definitely reconsider your design and approach. The most obvious being that 200+ iframes just to represent a game board is overkill. Making use of Javascript and AJAX/XHR to manage parts of the game client-side will also improve user experience, decrease server load, and build valuable skills in modern web app development.

I like PHP and despise JS more than most, but there's no getting away from it if you want to make cool apps on the internet.

Comment: There IS a fare share of javascript of course : the move evaluator mostly works upon $onLoad variable passed to the body tag after processing what to output (error message, hand to board, board to hand, attacks, not much to it really). It,s the consequential chain of events that's intricate...
The 200 frames are not all on auto-refresh that would indeed crash my cheap server... only 1 script reloads over and over and, checking for refresh lines in the db (table having 4 columns : target_frame,script_to_invoke,side,job_id). One roll of it will rarely refresh more than 5 frames... Still, thanks